# SQL - Problema ao encontrar relação de uma tabela com ela mesma

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, query, tabela-html

Boa noite. Criei a seguinte relação entre uma tabela chamada "Disciplina" que possui os campos "id" e "nome".
Uma disciplina possui outra disciplina como pré-requisito. Com isso, criei uma tabela auxiliar nomeada de pre_requisito, onde os campos são "id_disciplina_requisito" e "id_disciplina".
Contudo, o que eu preciso fazer é encontrar o nome das disciplinas que são pré requisitos de uma disciplina cujo nome é informado na consulta SQL.
Segue foto do esquema:
[esquema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WE6r.png)

Se alguém conseguir me dar um help agradeço, tentei todo tipo de join, etc, mas sem sucesso

Comment: Um `SELECT d.nome from disciplina as d INNER JOIN pre_requisito as r ON d.id = r.id_disciplina_requisito WHERE d.id = ?` retorna o esperado?

Comment: Não informe imagens , informe o esquema das tabelas em texto , informe somente a tag do Banco em questão (mysql ou postgresql).

Answer (score -2):

Tentei aqui o seguinte:

```
SELECT name FROM disciplinas WHERE id = 
(SELECT id_prerequisito FROM pre-requisito WHERE id_disciplina = 
(SELECT id FROM disciplinas WHERE name = "bolinha" LIMIT 1));
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Não entendi muito bem se você vai informar o NOME da disciplina a ser buscada ou se você tem o ID dela.
Por isso, vou prever as duas situações abaixo.

Na situação onde você vai fazer uma busca pelo nome da disciplina principal (que não seria o recomendado para evitar erros de digitação), o SQL seria:

```
SELECT principal.id AS id_principal, principal.nome AS nome_principal, requisito.id AS id_requisito, requisito.nome AS nome_requisito FROM disciplina AS principal LEFT JOIN disciplina AS requisito ON requisito.id = relacao.id_disciplina_requisito INNER JOIN pre_requisito AS relacao ON relacao.id_disciplina = principal.id WHERE principal.nome = "NOME DA DISCIPLINA EM VARIAVEL";
```

Se você tiver o ID da disciplina principal a ser buscada, é quase a mesma coisa...

```
SELECT principal.id AS id_principal, principal.nome AS nome_principal, requisito.id AS id_requisito, requisito.nome AS nome_requisito FROM disciplina AS principal LEFT JOIN disciplina AS requisito ON requisito.id = relacao.id_disciplina_requisito INNER JOIN pre_requisito AS relacao ON relacao.id_disciplina = principal.id WHERE principal.id = "ID DA DISCIPLINA EM VARIAVEL";
```

E se por acaso você não precisar do nome da disciplina principal a ser listada, apenas as relações, e tiver o ID...

```
SELECT requisito.id AS id_requisito, requisito.nome AS nome_requisito FROM disciplina AS requisito INNER JOIN pre_requisito AS relacao ON relacao.id_disciplina = "ID DA DISCIPLINA EM VARIAVEL" AND relacao.id_disciplina_requisito = requisito.id;
```

Espero que uma dessas formas resolva o seu problema, que parece ser algum trabalho escolar, pela forma simples de estrutura e porque é um tema padrão de trabalho.

Comment: Idente a sql , difícil ler uma sql numa linha só.

Comment: Não sabia que o formatador de código do stackoverflow não fazia isso automaticamente.  E não entendi o motivo de -4, mas tudo bem.  Não respondo mais.

Comment: cara, voce me ajudou, vlw

Comment: Se resolveu o seu problema, marque como resposta aceita.